# Arduino: while (Serial.available()==0) gives input

Tags: arduino

I am trying to input GPS coordinate into the serial monitor to use in my drone project

However, whenever I try to input GPS coordinate, it automatically writes one of the GPS coordinates without my input.  For example, GPS latitude is shown as 0.00, but the program waits for GPS Longitude info.

For a detailed situation please look at the picture attached.

[image]

```
int GPSNumCor;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin (115200);
  Serial.print("What is the number of your GPS Coordinate?  ");
  while (Serial.available() == 0);
  GPSNumCor = Serial.parseInt();
  Serial.println(GPSNumCor);
  delay (200);
  float GPSLat[GPSNumCor], GPSLon[GPSNumCor];
  for (int i = 0; i < GPSNumCor; i++)
  {
    if (i == 0)
    {
      Serial.println("What is your 1st GPS Coordinate");
    }
    if (i == 1)
    {
      Serial.println("What is your 2nd GPS Coordinate");
    }
    if (i == 2)
    {
      Serial.println("What is your 3rd GPS Coordinate");
    }
    if (i > 2)
    {
      Serial.print("What is your ");
      Serial.print(i + 1);
      Serial.println(" th GPS Coordinate");
    }
    delay(200);
    Serial.print ("Latitude: ");
    while (Serial.available() == 0);
    GPSLat[i] = Serial.parseFloat();
    Serial.println(GPSLat[i]);
    Serial.print("Longitude: ");
    while (Serial.available() == 0);
    GPSLon[i] = Serial.parseFloat();
    Serial.println(GPSLon[i]);
  }
}
```

It has to wait for all input until I make an input to the program, but it does not wait.

I know while (Serial.available()==0) is a way to go, but I do not know why it would not work.

Answer (score 1):

First, there's no reason to use `while (Serial.available() == 0);`. The `parseFloat` function you are about to use waits for data to be available and, if it didn't, merely checking for zero wouldn't be sufficient anyway because that would stop waiting as soon as a single character was available.

So here's why that `while` loop is a bad idea:

1. If you really do need to wait for the input before calling `parseFloat`, this won't do it. It only waits until at least one character is received and the coordinates may be more than one character.
2. The `parseFloat` function doesn't return until it has read an entire float anyway. So it already waits for you.

But that's not your problem. Think about the input stream, say it's "11.0`<newline>`22.0`newline`44.0". Where is the code to read the spaces between those numbers? When `parseFloat` tries to read a space, it returns a zero, as the documentation says. That's why you're getting zeroes -- you don't have any code to do anything with the separators between the floats.

Think about how `parseFloat` must work when it reads "12.34`newline`". First it reads the `1` and has no idea whether that's the whole number of not, so it keeps checking. Then it reads the "2.34" and still has no idea it has the whole number. Not until it sees the `newline` does it know that 12.34 is the correct float to return. But it does not consume the newline. Why? Because that might mean something.

With the code you showed, your next call to `parseFloat` will then try to read the newline and see that this is not a valid character to be part of a floating point number. So, as the documentation says, it will return zero.

Look closely at `parseFloat`'s documentation to find out how to correctly match the delimiters in your serial stream. The `parseFloat` function has the ability to  behave differently, consuming and ignoring delimeters rather than returning zero.

Comment: When I try to input number into GPSLat, program ignores and continues without waiting for my input.

Comment: @JasonJu That's because you have no code to parse anything but the numbers. There must, at least, be something in your input stream separating the numbers. See the documentation for `parseFloat`.

Comment: I checked, and I get 1 for Serial.available() after my input for GPSNumCor even though no input was made after.  I don't think parseFloat is the problem over here.

Comment: @JasonJu Of course you get 1. Think about it, what else could it be? You necessarily have received a coordinate followed by some character that indicated that you received the entire coordinate, for example "123.32<newline>" or "123.32," or "123.32 ". Your call to `parseFloat` is broken, as I explained, so it doesn't do anything with the newline, space, comma, or whatever. So it's still there when you call `available`. Why are you calling `available`? What do you think it does for you?

Comment: Because i used while(Serial.available()==0) to make the serial monitor wait for my input.

Comment: As I explained, that makes no sense for two reasons. First, `parseFloat` waits for input anyway. Second, how is waiting for one character going to do you any good? You'd still need to wait for the others. So if you did need it, it would be totally inadequate.

Comment: Found solution.  used Serial.read() to reset the serial.available to 0.

Comment: @JasonJu That's a bad solution as it creates race conditions should the Arduino ever be slow enough that one of the characters you want to read is in the buffer when you enter your loop. You may, for example, lose the first character of the coordinate. Why are you looking for not-right ways to do this when the right way is so simple?

Comment: Because I really have no idea what you want to tell me, because I genuinely can't understand what you are saying.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how it work, I just add `Serial.read()` in every time I want to read.

If u don't want to add `Serial.read()`, u can also use old version like 1.6.0, it still work fine but it don't work when u make like C# Serial app.

Just add `Serial.read()`, it work fine every place.

```
void setup() {
   // put your setup code here, to run once:
   Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
   // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
   while(Serial.available()==0){}

   int r=Serial.parseInt();
   Serial.println(r);

   Serial.read(); // it work fine

   while(Serial.available()==0){}

   int g=Serial.parseInt();
   Serial.println(g);

   Serial.read();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Serial Monitor window, in the drop-down menu on the bottom-right, change from "**Newline**" to "**No line ending**" and that will solve the problem (by preventing the Serial Monitor from automatically entering zero value(s)).

Both the `parseInt()` and `parseFloat()` have a hard time reading other data types (this also includes white spaces such as new lines) than the ones specified, and as a result they automatically return zero.

**Reference:** This page on ***Programming electronics*** offers valuable, detailed explanations (look for a paragraph with bold text):
https://www.programmingelectronics.com/parseint/